# Is Workplace SE not community moderated like other SE sites?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, moderation

Been using many SE sites (starting with SO) for a few years now. Questions are closed/put on hold in most sites by 5 votes from people who have crossed a certain threshold of points. I myself vote for closing questions regularly on Stack Overflow.

However, here my question was put on hold by just one person - [How to prepare for people who have been made offers not joining](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/28200/how-to-prepare-for-people-who-have-been-made-offers-not-joining)

So does Workplace SE follow a different moderation model than other SE sites?

Answer (score 8):

On all sites on the network, [Moderators have binding votes](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/). Some sites use them more than others.

The post in question had received flags about a large number of comments that needed to be cleaned up. I read through the post and the comments and noted that the question was hypothetical, and members of the community were not able to get clarifications to help answer the question as a result of it being hypothetical. Rather than trying to sort through all the comments (and delete important clarifying information), I voted to close it instead.

All sites on the SE network have the same page in the [help center](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask):

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions **based on actual problems that you face**. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

Hypothetical questions are often problematic because you are making assumptions about what the problem is, which makes it hard for people to answer. For instance the very first comment asks: *"Why are people turning down the job offer 20 days later? Are they accepting a counteroffer from their current company?"* to which you responded, *"it could be any reason - does it matter - I am sure there must be a percentage of people who accept the offer and then not join."*

The top answer says *"If people are turning you down after accepting your initial offer then you need to ask yourself why. You should also be asking them why, if possible, too."* But the catch is that nobody is turning you down, because this is a hypothetical, and all we end up is a bunch of people hypothesizing about potential causes of a made-up problem.

That isn't so useful.

You have three options open to you:

1. Edit your question to actually flesh out the problem and make it specific enough to answer
2. Edit your question to better explain *why* you feel this will become a problem, and ask how to prevent it if possible
3. Disagree with me and find 5 members of the community willing to cast reopen votes